# msys+mingw - is there installer or at least .tar.lzma/.zip?

Tags: mingw, msys

I try to install n'th time the msys+mingw - however with little success. I need the minimal developer system (standard tools such as sed/awk+autotools+gcc) however each time something is not working (for example currently when I try to run autotools m4 goes into some error loop on AC_INIT).

I know they stopped providing installer 'for easy update of components' and they are working on something but maybe there is something unofficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TakeoffGW](http://takeoffgw.sourceforge.net/) - basicly a port/repository of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installer for [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/).